# Operador mayor o igual que no funciona bien en js

Tags: javascript

Tengo un menu de productos donde obtengo el precio y la cantidad minima de ellos, y cuando lo agrego a la tabla funciona pero cuando escojo otro producto, no sigue la regla que le asigne, alguna idea de que esta pasando:
Aqui mi js:

```
var x = $("#txtCantidad").val();
var y = $("#cant").attr("ml");
  if (x>=y) {
     alert("Agregando");
  }else{
     alert("no se puede agregar");
  }
```

el atributo (ml) es un atributo que va cambiando segun el producto que selecciono, funciona a veces y a veces no, no entiendo porque.

Comment: Intentaste hacer un `parseFloat`

Comment: Fijate que no estés comparando texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solucion sería que el valor que tomes de los dos elementos los parsees a numerico, siempre y cuando quieras utilizar valores enteros.

Para ello podrias multiplicar el valor obtenido por 1

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $("#txtCantidad").val() * 1;
  var y = $("#cant").attr("ml") * 1;
  
  if (x>=y) {
     alert("Agregando");
  }else{
     alert("no se puede agregar");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtCantidad" value="50">
<div id="cant" ml="30"></div>
```

Espero te haya podido ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Si son dos valores numéricos, lo primero que deberías hacer es parsearlo ya que de lo contrario estarías comparando un `string`. Puede ser utilizando `parseInt` para enteros o `parseFloat` para decimales:

```
var x = parseFloat($("#txtCantidad").val());
var y = parseFloat($("#cant").attr("ml"));
if (x>=y) {
  alert("Agregando");
}else{
  alert("no se puede agregar");
}
```

Comment: Parece que el problema derivaba en una vareable con el mismo nombre y no limpiaba el attr, igual lo agrego ya que manejo valor tipo float. Gracias.